# How to control log level in ASP.Net core Integration tests

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to limit the amount the log information being printed when running integration tests for asp.net core. Currently, everything down to debug level is being printed and it obscures useful information. I would really like to restrict it to warning and above.

I am running integration tests using the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-webapplicationfactory

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> 
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Create a new service provider.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            // Add a database context (ApplicationDbContext) using an in-memory 
            // database for testing.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

            // Build the service provider.
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
            // context (ApplicationDbContext).
            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var logger = scopedServices
                    .GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                // Ensure the database is created.
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                try
                {
                    // Seed the database with test data.
                    Utilities.InitializeDbForTests(db);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the database. Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[4]
      Hosting started
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[0]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly BackEnd.Api
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET http://localhost/test
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware[0]
      Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
...lots more dbug logs...
```

Things I have tried in the `ConfigureWebHost`:

```cs
            builder.ConfigureLogging(o =>
            {
                o.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
            });
```

No effect. I could not come up with any other combination of levels and filters that had any effect.

```cs
            builder.ConfigureLogging(o =>
            {
                o.ClearProviders();
            });
```

Stops all logging, but that's not really what I want.

Comment: Could you please explain, how you configured logs output for CustomWebApplicationFactory? Because the sample from your link doesn't produce logs when running tests.

Comment: 4 years too late, but hope this helps someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222453/193634

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `AddFilter` like

```
builder.ConfigureLogging(o=> {
            //o.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
            o.AddFilter(logLevel => logLevel >= LogLevel.Warning);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this for my case. In the `appsettings.json` for the asp.net core app I was testing, was the following config:

```
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
```

It seems that this would override any of the filtering or level changes I made in the code for the integration tests. Changing this level to `Warning` resolved my issue.