# .net core 3.0, issue with IClassFixture, "unresolved constructor arguments: ITestOutputHelper output"

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-core-3.0

I made a repo for the issue I have with Integration testing upgrading to .net core 3.0 :
https://github.com/ranouf/TestingWithDotNetCore3_0

When I launch the test, I have this issue:
Message:

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Class fixture type 'MyIntegrationTests.TestServerFixture' had one or more
>   unresolved constructor arguments: ITestOutputHelper output) (The
>   following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data:
>   TestServerFixture testServerFixture)
>       ---- Class fixture type 'MyIntegrationTests.TestServerFixture' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: ITestOutputHelper output
>       ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestServerFixture testServerFixture   Stack Trace: 
>       ----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----
>       ----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----

Here is the constructor:

```
public class WeatherForecastController_Tests : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture>
{
    public WeatherForecastController_Tests(TestServerFixture testServerFixture, ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Client = testServerFixture.Client;
        Output = output;
    }
```

TestStartup:

```
public class TestStartup : Startup
{
    public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {

    }

    public override void SetUpDataBase(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // here is where I use the InMemoryDatabase 
    }
}
```

TestServerFixture:

```
public class TestServerFixture : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    private IHost _host;
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get; }

    public TestServerFixture(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Output = output;
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }

    // never called but this is where i was previously building up the server
    //
    protected override TestServer CreateServer(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        return base.CreateServer(builder);
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        _host = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = _host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            InitializeDataBase(services, Output);
        }

        _host.Start();
        return _host;
    }

    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(new XunitLoggerProvider(Output));
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseTestServer();
            });

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<TestStartup>();
    }

    private void InitializeDataBase(IServiceProvider services, ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        try
        {
            output.WriteLine("Starting the database initialization.");
            //here is where is feed the Test DB
            output.WriteLine("The database initialization has been done.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output.WriteLine("An error occurred while initialization the database.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

So clearly, the Iod for TestServerFixture testServerFixture and ITestOutputHelper output doesnt work. How to make it work?

Comment: I was able to do it with .net core 2.0 and without WebApplicationFactory and IClassFixture.
Do you know maybe another way to do it in .net core 3.0?
It s interesting to be able to have some details when a test failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @Nkosi for your help, It helps me to find a solution :).
I was inspired by other websites too:

- https://andrewlock.net/converting-integration-tests-to-net-core-3/
- https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-integration-test-startup/

I updated the solution on my repo too

- [commit/3e588106f3588ac671e5bc8dbcb7b17d416fc1ee](https://github.com/ranouf/TestingWithDotNetCore3_0/commit/3e588106f3588ac671e5bc8dbcb7b17d416fc1ee))

Here are important parts:

TestServerFixture:

```
public class TestServerFixture : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get; set; }

    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders(); //All API logging providers are cleared
                logging.AddXunit(Output); //Internal extension which redirect all log to the ITestOutputHelper 
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                    .ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
                    {
                        //Without that, the client always returns 404
                        //(even if it has already been set in Startup.Configure)
                        services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                    });
            });

        return builder;
    }

    //ITestOutputHelper is set in the constructor of the Test class
    public TestServerFixture SetOutPut(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Output = output;
        return this;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        Output = null;
    }
}
```

WeatherForecastController_Tests:

```
public class WeatherForecastController_Tests : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture>
{
    public TestServerFixture TestServerFixture { get; private set; }
    public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get { return TestServerFixture.Output; } }

    public WeatherForecastController_Tests(TestServerFixture testServerFixture, ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        TestServerFixture = testServerFixture.SetOutPut(output);
        Client = testServerFixture.CreateClient();
    }

    [...]
}
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions to improve the code or questions :)

Comment: Well... what do you know..., this works... thanks for sharing, I found this from a GitHub link someone shared.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your code and after some research I have come to the conclusion that injecting `ITestOutputHelper` into `TestServerFixture` via constructor injection is not feasible. I looked into property injection as well but I believe the it may end up getting used before the property has been populated.

The main issue here is the flow of how things get invoked when the `WebApplicationFactory` is created.

By creating the `Client` in the constructor, it triggers a sequence of events that prevent you from being able to make use of the `ITestOutputHelper`

I suggest deferring the creation of the `Client` so that dependencies can be set before.

```
public class TestServerFixture : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup> {
    private Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => return Server.CreateClient());

    private IHost _host;
    public HttpClient Client => client.Value;
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get; set; }

    public TestServerFixture(){
        //...
    }

    //...all other code remains the same
}
```

Note the `Lazy<HttpClient>`. This is to defer the creation of the client so that the `ITestOutputHelper` can be populate first.

```
public class WeatherForecastController_Tests : IClassFixture<TestServerFixture> {
    public WeatherForecastController_Tests(TestServerFixture testServerFixture, ITestOutputHelper output) {
        Output = output;
        testServerFixture.Output = Output;
        Client = testServerFixture.Client;            
    }

    //...
```