# AspNetCore.TestHost: How to get log output from the in-process server?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, integration-testing, asp.net-core-testhost

I am using the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost** to integration-test my ASP.NET Core web service application.

```
var testServer = new TestServer(
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseConfiguration(configuration));
var client = testServer.CreateClient();
```

This works, but I have a problem: If there's an unexpected error on the server side, it typically just throws "Internal Server Error" and I have to debug to see what it does.

Of course I can improve the error messages from my server, but in addition to that ***I want to be able to see log output from the server***.

Is this possible?

I am thinking that when I create my `TestServer` object above, perhaps I can inject a log sink such as the one from **Serilog.Sinks.InMemory** and then inspect the contents of that. The `WebHostBuilder` has a method `ConfigureLogging`, but I couldn't figure out how to do what I want.

Comment: This works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222453/193634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible :)

You need the **Serilog.AspNetCore** nuget package, plus (obviously) **Serilog.Sinks.InMemory** for the sink.

```cs
var testServer = new TestServer(
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseSerilog((ctx, conf) => conf.WriteTo.InMemory()) // That's pretty much it.
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseConfiguration(cBuilder.Build()));

// Then, in the tests, you can access it like this. But you probably know.
InMemorySink.Instance
    .Should()
    .HaveMessage(...)
```

If doesn't work, let me know and I will edit the answer. I tested it, and it works for me.

Comment: What NuGet packages do I need in order to get the extension method _UseSerilog_?

Comment: I've tried to reference **Serilog**, **Serilog.Extensions.Hosting**, **Serilog.Extensions.Logging** and **Serilog.Sinks.InMemory**, but none of them give me this extension method.

Comment: The one you need to use is **Serilog.AspNetCore**, plus **Serilog.Sinks.InMemory** for the sink.