# Getting Console Logging in Visual Studio Test Runner when using TestServer for integration tests

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi, web-api-testing

When performing integration tests with my module directly (skipping API), I get my console output in the Visual Studio test runner just fine.

When I try to perform integration tests including my API with TestServer, I get all of the logs to the Debug window if I run in debug, but I don't get any output in Visual Studio test runner when running normally.

Am using NUnit.

**Integration Tests Setup (skipping API)**

```
public class Tests
{
    private ILogger _loggerForModule;

    [SetUp]
    public void InitializeModule()
    {
        // Create the logger
        using (ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(b =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
            b.AddDebug();
        }))
        {
            _loggerForModule = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Module.Logging");
        }

        // Initialize the module with the logger created for it.
        ModuleInitializer.Initialize(_loggerForModule);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TestMyMethod()
    {
        ModuleCommands.ExecuteCommand(new DoMethodCommand("method param"));
    }
}
```

When I run this test all of the logging performed within the DoMethodCommand in my module is logged to the console in the test runner.

**Integration Tests with API**

```
public class Tests
{
    private TestServer _testServer;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void SetupTestServerAndHttpClient()
    {
        _testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<MyWebAPIProject.Startup>();

        _httpClient = _testServer.CreateClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TestMyAPIMethod()
    {
        await _httpClient.PostAsync("myapiroute", "method param");
    }
}
```

**MyWebAPIProject.Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ILogger loggerForModule;

    using (ILoggerFactory loggerFactory.Create(b => 
    {
        b.AddConsole();
        b.AddDebug();
    }))
    {
        loggerForModule = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Module.Logging")
    }

    ModuleInitializer.Initialize(loggerForModule);
}
```

Using this above, the API passes the command into my module and everything executes OK and I can see all module logging in debug window, but I get nothing in the Visual Studio test runner output.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Nunit, I has having the same problem, and I found an answer over at [AspNetCore.TestHost: How to get log output from the in-process server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532416/aspnetcore-testhost-how-to-get-log-output-from-the-in-process-server)

I used Serilog.Sinks.InMemory, added the below:

```
    public class InMemoryAPIHosting
    {
        public WebApplicationFactory<Startup> API { get; set; }

        public InMemoryAPIHosting()
        {
            API = new APIWebApplicationFactory()
                      .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                      {
                          //This allows us to access Serilog entries created while the API is running during integration tests. We can inspect them using InMemorySink.Instance.LogEvents.
                          builder.UseSerilog((ctx, conf) => conf.WriteTo.InMemory());
                      });
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            API.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Finally, in my test method, I created a method that I can call like this:

```
        //Helper method that checks the In Memory API logs and writes it to the test output if it finds any
        public static void CheckSeriLogEvents(bool throwOnError = false)
        {
            //After starting up the in memory API, let's review the log items to see if there are any errors. If so, spit them out into the test output.
            if (InMemorySink.Instance.LogEvents.Any(x => x.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error))
            {
                //There was an error in the logs of the In Memory API! Spit it out.
                TestLogger.WriteTestOutput("Error in Memory API. Please review the log data.");
                foreach (var logEvent in InMemorySink.Instance.LogEvents.Where(x => x.Level >= Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning))
                {
                    TestLogger.WriteTestOutput(logEvent.Timestamp + ": " + logEvent.RenderMessage(), false);
                }

                //End the test immediately with an error, if a throw was requested
                if (throwOnError)
                {
                    throw new SerilogInMemoryStartupException("Error in Memory API. Please review the log data. Test aborted.");
                }
            }
        }
```