# Getting detailed logs from integration test calling local .net API

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, integration-testing

I have a .NET core solution containing an API & an integration test, and I want a way to get logging sent to the test's standard output.

For instance, this API throws an exception on the endpoint as below:

```
app.MapGet("/todos", () => {
    Console.WriteLine("Something is going wrong.");
    throw new System.Exception("Some error!");
});
```

And my test:

```
    public async Task GetTodos()
    {
        await using var application = new TodoApplication();

        var client = application.CreateClient();
        var todos = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<string>>("/todos");

        Assert.Empty(todos);
    }
```

Produces the output:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

I can fiddle with the app builder / middleware to spit out verbatim exception messages, but the logging I can't seem to get working.

I have tried adding a console logger to the integration test host, as below, but I do not see any logging messages when I run my tests. I would have liked to have seen "Something is going wrong." per the example without changing the test code - but would rather send logs to the test output.

```
namespace Sample.Tests
{
    class TodoApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
    {
        protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureLogging((builder) => builder.AddConsole());
            return base.CreateHost(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AspNetCore.TestHost: How to get log output from the in-process server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532416/aspnetcore-testhost-how-to-get-log-output-from-the-in-process-server)

Comment: I think that does, thanks @MichaelFreidgeim.